# Unity iOS 10 Loading level terminates due to memory issue

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

Recently my game has started crashing randomly when loading a specific scene. This is weird because it's one of the least populated scenes and I use Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets() as well. Nothing I seem to try, including a complete remake of the scene works. It works fine on Android and used to work fine on iOS.

If anyone has any similar experiences or knowledge of this issue and it's fix that would be great! Thanks

*EDIT:* I'm using Unity 5.4.1f1 and Xcode 8, I build for either iOS 9.1 or iOS 10, it crashes on both.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the scene on your computer and comparing the memory usage to other scenes?

Comment: Turns out the artist forgot to downsize two of the images I was using to make the level and I didn't think to check it. Ended up just downscaling the sprites and all is well. Always check your resolutions kids!

Comment: if you solved the problem, please add an answer and accept it